# Confused in Taking The Number Of Table View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have 6 buttons in a View (ViewOne). Every button should show a tableView on the same View.(the buttons should not disappear and the table view should appear on the remaining view)

so far i have taken one view controller (ViewTwo for Button1) and pushing the view with required data by using

```
[self.view addSubview:ViewTwo.view];
```

As the data in the tableView varies,Should i take 6 ViewControllers for each tableView or is there any other easy achieve to do it??

Comment: For same kind of tableview u can keep the same table & just change the table cells data.

Comment: No..there is no need to take 6 viewcotrollers....in just one view, every time you check which button is clicked and reload tableview...this is the common way to do this...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one UITableView instead of 6 different viewControllers. and try reloadData property of tableView with Button Press event.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no need of tacking different view for each tableview  u just load you data in (NSArray or NSDictionary Whatever you r using to display the cell.textlable.text) on click of every button.

1.first remove the all object From (NSArray/NSDictionary)

2.Add new object in (NSArray/NSDictionary).

3.and than Reload your Table view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to take 6 UIViewControllers.You can do this functionality in just one view,every time you check which button is clicked and reload tableview data.This is the best way to do this.